# Is there any quick way to add same php file to many folders?

Tags: php, directory

I have a index.php file. In my root folder, there are approximately 200 folders. I want to add index.php file to all 200 folder. Instead of copy-paste, is there a quick way to add it?

Comment: why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: You should probably rethink your design if you ever need to do this...

Comment: What web-server software are you using?  You can usually configure it to do all sorts of clever stuff along these lines...

Comment: sounds like the index.php contains `die("Directory listing denied.");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, like all the other people have already said, there is probably something wrong in your design. If you want to make sure people can't access it, just use Apache to do that, not PHP. If you still feel the need to add an index.php file to every single directory, here's how:

```
<?php
$content = 'Your content';

$files = glob( './*' );
foreach( $files as $file ) {
    if( is_dir( $file ) && is_writable( $file ) ) {
        file_put_contents( $file . '/index.php', $content );
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one level penetration. use recursion for multi-level penetration

Comment: @VIPINJAIN See the question: "In my root folder, there are approximately 200 folders. I want to add index.php file to all 200 folder." It doesn't say anything about subdirectories.

Comment: Hi, Berry thank you for your code and it works. index.php file is added to all my folder. But there is a little problem. In index.php, $content is added. But I have my own index.php file and it's code is long. How can I solve this problem. That is to say; I want to add/copy my index.php which I write.

Comment: Then `$content = file_get_contents( 'index.php' );` should work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a quick way to do this but I feel there are better ways to do what you need.

Is the index file purely to stop people seeing folders?
If so try putting `IndexIgnore *` into your .htaccess

More info here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess11.shtml

Comment: not to stop people seeing my folder. Only I need add that file to folders. Is my design wrong?

Comment: Why are you adding the same file to all the folders?

Comment: My design is : I have 200 books and I want to show them like mydomain.com/book1/index.php. So, index.php display information about that book. For this reason I have to copy index.php file to 200 folder. Is there quick way?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
function putindexfiles($putfile,$start=""){
    $files = glob($start.'*',GLOB_MARK);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_dir($file)){
            copy($putfile,$file.'index.php');
            putindexfiles($putfile,$file);
        }
    }
}
```

This function use recursion so all sub-directories also get affected.

and $putfile is the path to the file whose contents are to be placed in index.php of every folder. this script creates all index.php automatically in each folder.

while using the function you dont need to provide the $start as this is default parameter is the directory in which the script is placed.

Enjoy